# Query sql to find row's count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my MySQL db i have these 3 tables:

```
ACCOUNT (primary key is name)
 name
 directory
 birthdate
 sex

FILES (primary key is id)
 id (autoincrement)
 name (account foreign key)
 filename
 uploaded_date

CHECKED (primary key is the couple name - filename)
 name (account foreign key)
 filename (files foreign key)
```

I want to make a query that shows a resulting table like this:

```
RESULT
 name - directory - birthdate - sex - filename uploaded_date - checkedCount
```

Where in checkedCount column i want to have the existing row's count number in CHECKED table for every unique filename.

I tried with this but i had no success:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM account NATURAL JOIN files) AS table_alias LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, count(*) AS checkedCount FROM checked) AS checked_alias ON table_alias.filename = checked_alias.filename
```

Currently in ACCOUNT table there are only 2 row, in FILES table 6 rows and in CHECKED tables there are 6 rows with the same name from ACCOUNT and all others 6 unique filenames from FILES.

I can't understand why in my resulting table in checkedCount columns i have all values setted to null, except one that is setted to 6. My goal should be to have all six rows with checkedCount = 1 since every FILE in FILES table is used one times in CHECK table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
    a.*, f.filename, f.uploaded_date, IFNULL(c.cnt, 0) as 'checkedCount'
FROM
    account a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN files f ON a.name = f.name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM checked GROUP BY 1) c ON a.name=c.name
```

Comment: Thanks, after some attempts it worked. Only one warning, i think it's better to use GROUP BY filename since if column table order is modified, the query's result changes

Comment: @lubilis, Sure, to do that just change the last line to `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT filename, COUNT(*) FROM checked GROUP BY 1) c ON f.filename=c.filename`

Answer (score 1):

So I'm guessing you know how `count` works right? By using a count you need a group by clause.

Example:

```
SELECT count(name) as count, name FROM CHECKED GROUP BY name
```

Now here's the problem. You have a big nasty join that you want to do a count on. So lets join the tables, alias them, and then do a count on a field.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.name AS name, ACCOUNT.directory AS directory, ACCOUNT.birthDate AS birthdate, ACCOUNT.sex AS sex, FILES.filename AS filename, FILES.uploaded_date AS uploaded_date, count(CHECKED.filename) AS checkedCount
FROM ACCOUNT JOIN FILES ON ACCOUNT.name = FILES.name JOIN CHECKED ON FILES.filename = CHECKED.filename GROUP BY CHECKED.filename;
```

This... Big... Long... Confusing... join statement should do what you want, but I would also take a look at [MySQL Count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) and [MySQL Aliasing](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to make things prettier.

Comment: Thanks, this should be the right way. I've only one issue now. With the GROUP BY CHECKED.name in my results all those files that don't exist in CHECKED table are skipped. I tried with LEFT OUTER JOIN with no success

Comment: Whoops. Hmm lets try an edit with count(CHECKED.filename) and GROUP BY CHECKED.filename instead to see if that does what you want @lubilis

Comment: Sorry, i was already trying with CHECKED.filename with no success. I think that using this query it's normal that some values are skipped

Answer (score 0):

If I got this straight, the following godê should work for you:

```
SELECT 
 A.name
,A.directory
,A.birthdate
,A.sexfilename
,F.uploaded_date
,(CASE WHEN C.filename IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS checkedCount
FROM 
ACCOUNT A
LEFT JOIN FILES F
     ON  A.name = F.name
LEFT JOIN CHECKED C
     ON F.filename = C.filename
```

Try it out and let me know.

I do not know what your DB is about, but can't your "CHECKED" table be converted into a "checked" column inside your FILES table? As it is a 1-1 relation? Maybe that will make it easier.

Comment: I can't convert CHECKED table into a "checked" column inside FILES table since one file can be checked from one user but not from another one

Comment: Files are unique, there can be many distinct files and every file can be checked or not from a distinct user